# Wordpress substitute string in post

Tags: php, wordpress, post, subset

Hi I have rss feed from another page to my wordpress site. It automaticly creating post from rss feed. But in rss feed is link to image and I need change it to another link. 
I make this script

```
<?php 
$link="http://www.example.com/thumbs/329/t2_f2ba40a1092b2039a1cf71d2a2b76e91.jpg";
$start = strpos($link, 'thumbs');
$end = strpos($link, 't2_'  )+3;
$length = $end - $start;
$vypis = substr($link, $start, $length);
$new = str_replace($vypis, "i/", $link);
echo $new;

?>
```

It works fine but I dont know where I should place this script in wordpress template. And how get automaticly from post that link and get it to `$link` Any ideas please?

Here is plugin http://wordpress.org/plugins/feedwordpress/ for rss feed. It automaticly creates post and it work in any template. The code for loop is this one `<?php the_content('Celý článek &raquo;');  ?>`

Example of post

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/spray-on-clothes-34751.html"><img src="http://www.example.com/thumbs/329/t2_f2ba40a1092b2039a1cf71d2a2b76e91.jpg"/><br />Click to see the full pic.</a><br/><div class="feedflare">
<a href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/example?a=JFKec5JGE9M:rVB15gLhJKs:yIl2AUoC8zA"><img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/example?d=yIl2AUoC8zA" border="0"></img></a> <a href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/example?a=JFKec5JGE9M:rVB15gLhJKs:V_sGLiPBpWU"><img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/example?i=JFKec5JGE9M:rVB15gLhJKs:V_sGLiPBpWU" border="0"></img></a> <a href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/example?a=JFKec5JGE9M:rVB15gLhJKs:qj6IDK7rITs"><img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/example?d=qj6IDK7rITs" border="0"></img></a> <a href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/example?a=JFKec5JGE9M:rVB15gLhJKs:gIN9vFwOqvQ"><img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/example?i=JFKec5JGE9M:rVB15gLhJKs:gIN9vFwOqvQ" border="0"></img></a>
</div><img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~r/example/~4/JFKec5JGE9M" height="1" width="1"/>
```

Comment: We need to see more of your code (like the source code to the page/post template or widget that includes the RSS feed rendering)

Comment: I edit my question. Do you need more information or is it enought?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, then you should be able to replace `the_content('Celý článek &raquo;')` with the following code. It will pull the page content (without outputting to the browser), replace the URL using your code, and then output to the browser. The trick will be in identifying the URL each time. I'll need to see the full post source, to be able to use regular expressions or other method to identify the URL to replace.

```
$content = get_the_content(); // get post content
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content); // apply formatting
$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content); // apply formatting

// This specifically will need modification, to identify the URL... 
// I would need to see example post content to find out how

$link="http://www.example.com/thumbs/329/t2_f2ba40a1092b2039a1cf71d2a2b76e91.jpg";

$start = strpos($link, 'thumbs');
$end = strpos($link, 't2_'  )+3;
$length = $end - $start;
$vypis = substr($link, $start, $length);
$new = str_replace($vypis, "i/", $link);

$content = str_replace( $link, $new, $content ); // Replace URL in content
echo $content; // Output to browser
```

Comment: Thanks I make some edit of code and it works!